# Custom method redirect in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a custom method in my model, which finds a record by name:

```
def find_city
  Place.find_by_name(city_name)
end
```

I can call this method in my view with `place_path(@place.find_city)`, which works great when a place with the appropriate name exists. What I would like to be able to do is write in a redirect for when the place doesn't exist, and I'm unsure about where the logic should go. Basically, I would like to write something like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @place.find_city.blank?
    format.html { redirect_to :action => "new" }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "show" }
  end
end
```

...but I would still like the controller to respond to `place_path(@place)` in the usual manner as well. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: sorry for the confusion, should have explained my example further. I have a Place model that has both 'city_name' and 'name' as attributes. The `find_city` custom method that I detailed above finds the place whose name matches the city_name for another place eg.

```
Place.name = "foo"  
Place.city_name = "baz"
```

So therefore `Place.find_city` gives the record where `Place.name = "baz"`. Cheers!

Comment: How do you know if the user want to go to @place or to the city of the @place? I think you need to explain better what you want to do.. I couldn't really get it.. When you do a place_path(@place) you want the user to be redirected to the city or to the @place? Are they the same think? Sorry, I got really confused =)

Comment: I've added a bit of a clarification above, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to create a helper method for this problem - what I've described above might seem a bit of an unorthodox approach, but I only need the `find_city` method to create a links bar for each place, so I don't think I really need to create a separate city model, or define a formal self-referential relationship. Just in case anyone might find this useful, I've created a `links_bar` helper:

```
module PlacesHelper

  def links_bar(place)
    if place.city_name.blank?
       render "no_city_links"
    elsif place.find_city.nil?
      render "nil_find_city_links"
    else
      render "complete_links"
    end
  end

end
```

Each partial then has the required behaviour depending upon whether or not the `find_city` method returns a record or not.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

keep your model as

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base

  named_scope :by_name, lambda {|city|{:conditions => "name=#{city}"}}

end
```

in your controller

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController


  def index

    @city = City.by_name(<city name>)

    if @city.nil?

      <redirect to one place>

    else

      <redirect to another place>

    end

  end

end
```

and in your view access the @city parameter.

** Normally we shouldnt access Models directly from views. Either we should do it through controllers or helpers

Hope this helps

cheers

sameera

Comment: Thanks for your response - I actually don't have a City model, sorry I should have explained my problem a bit better! I've added a clarification above. Sorry!

Comment: Hi

In that case you can replace City with Place and should work. 

cheers

sameera